# Redirect to page with add page tab dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, tabs

Facebook recently notified they are [deprecating support for app profile pages](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/).

Apps created after Dec 10th no longer have the app page option, together with the 
"add to my page" functionality, and must use the new [Add page tab dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/).

After the user selects which page to add the application to, is there any way to 
redirect the user to the selected page?

Similar functionality existed in the "old" add to page dialog, e.g. 
`https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=MY_ADD_ID&pages=1`

Activating the dialog with a response function seems to bring no result.

`

```
// Add app to page
function addToPage() {
```

```
// calling the API ...
FB.ui({
        method: 'pagetab',
        redirect_uri: 'MY_URL',
    },function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
```

}

`
So, two questions: 
a) Is there any possibility for the app using the dialog to "know" which page was selected? 
b) Is there any way to redirect the user to the selected page.

Thx!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function addToPage() {

      // calling the API ...
      FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'pagetab'
        },
        function(response) {
            if (response != null && response.tabs_added != null) {

                $.each(response.tabs_added, function(pageid) {
                      alert(pageid);
                });
            }
        }
      );

      }
  </script>
```

Use above code...you will get page id of pages selected by the user

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for that, it works! 
Is there any documentation for these things? 

I got it to work with a slight code change: 
(Sorry, but couldn't get it to paste as code...) 

`   
function addToPage() {

    // calling the pagetab API
    FB.ui({
            method: 'pagetab'
        },
        function(response) {
            if (response && response.tabs_added) {
         for (pageid in response.tabs_added) { 
             alert(pageid); 
        } 
            } 
        }
    });
}
`

Comment: I cannot get the response from dialog when app in a page tab. Dont know why.

Answer (score 4):

but what if the user has a custom name for its page.

i modify  [devson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144290/devson).. code a bit

```
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'pagetab',
        redirect_uri: '',
    },
    function(response) {
        if (response != null && response.tabs_added != null) {

            $.each(response.tabs_added, function(pageid) {
                  FB.api(pageid, function(response) {
                  alert('redirect to ' + response.link);
                    });


            });

        }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

This used to be simple, using the facebook UI.("Add to My Page") Unfortunately facebook removed this.

You can add it using www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

I put this an html and publisched it below. Just visit, enter your app params, hit submit, and our done.

http://www.jibecompany.com/2012/add-a-facebook-page-tab-application-to-your-page